# adb -s devicenumber shell input keyevent ...java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission

Tags: adb, miui

I get the above error message if I try to emulate the keyboard via the adb command.
adb -s devicenumber shell input keyevent KEYCODE_DEL
This is what the "Redmi Note 8 pro" does to me, but also the "Redmi 12" but with the "Redmi 9" it worked for me...

Redmi 12 uses Android 13
Redmi 9 uses Android 12
Redmi Note 8 pro uses Android 11

The MIUI information from the phones I only have from Redmi 12(MIUI14.0.7) and from Redmi 8(MIUI12.5.7.0), Redmi 9 I unfortunately lost...

The MIUI information of the phones I have only from Redmi 12(MIUI14.0.7) and from Redmi 8(MIUI12.5.7.0), Redmi 9 I unfortunately lost...
Thank you for any help.

Other commands via adb work normally, only the ones regarding key emulation don't work.

Comment: I'll answer for myself.
It's the switch in the developer options
USB Debug (Security Settings)...
This switch is dependent on whether a SIM card is present.
I've tried without it and never managed to do so...:)